# VS Code search html DOM tree by css-selectors

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, css-selectors

Does any extension of VS Code provide search feature just like this in chrome developer tools:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/search-dom-tree-by-css-selector

For example, type ".row.h-100" and will be navigated to the following tag

```
<div class="row foo h-100 bar">
</div>
```

And what's more, does any extension provide "Goto Defined" functionality in css files?(like a reverse of CSS Peek's Goto Defination) 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-definition

Comment: I imagine such an extension would need to intelligently render a DOM tree on-the-fly for any page or fragment in order for selectors to work, turning Code much like a WYSIWYG editor. But due to the nature of HTML, what you see in the markup isn't always going to be what you get.

Comment: I want this too. Did you end up finding anything?

Comment: @Nadia No, I settled with alt-tabbing between chrome and vsc...

Comment: I haven't be able to find an extension either. But it shouldn't be difficult to implement. [elfinder](https://github.com/keeganstreet/element-finder) is a NodeJS command line app that allows searching for any CSS selector recursively in a directory or a list of files.